# What is the determinant of the sum of a diagonal matrix and a matrix of ones?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Given a square matrix, all elements outside of the main diagonal being equal to $1,$ what is its determinant?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219731/determinant-of-rank-one-update-of-identity-matrix (The chosen answer handles your case, even though the question doesn't)

Comment: @deinst I think that covers it. Would you mind copying the relevant part of that answer into an answer to this question so I can mark this as accepted? I can do this myself, too, if you don't want to.

Comment: @deinst Strictly speaking, the case that at least one of the diagonal entries is $1$ (i..e, singular $A$) is not covered in (6.2.3)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen When exactly one entry in the diagonal is $1$, the result is $\prod_i(a_{ii}-[a_{ii}\neq1]),$ where $[p]$ is the Iverson bracket. If more than one entry is $1$, the result is $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the matrix be
\begin{align}
A & = \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & d_2 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 1 & d_3 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & d_n
\end{bmatrix}\\
&
=
\begin{bmatrix}
d_1-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & d_2-1 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & d_3-1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & d_n-1
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
& = D+uu^T
\end{align}
where $D=\begin{bmatrix}
d_1-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & d_2-1 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & d_3-1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & d_n-1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $u^T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

If $D$ is invertible, from [Sylvester determinant theorem][1], we have
$$\det(D+uu^T) = \det(D)\det(I+D^{-1}uu^T) = \det(D) \det(I_{1 \times 1} + u^TD^{-1}u)$$

This gives us that the determinant is
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (d_k-1)\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac1{d_i-1}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^n (d_k-1) + \sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{\overset{k=1}{k \neq i}}^n (d_k-1)$$
[1]: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem)

Comment: The proof doesn't hold when D isn't invertible. Can this situation be proved separately?