# determinant of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given a matrix
\begin{equation}
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
c & a & b \\
b & c & a
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and $a,b,c$ are not all equal and are all positive. We HAVE That
\begin{equation}
Det(M)=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc>0
\end{equation}
where the inquality is true by AM-GM inequality.

Now if we perturb the matrix a little bit, say
\begin{equation}
M_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
c_2 & a_2 & b_2 \\
b_3 & c_3 & a_3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where the relative order remains unchanged, say $\forall i, j, k\in\{1,2,3\}$, $0<a_i<b_j<c_k$ if previously $a<b<c$,
I want to show a similar positive determinant
\begin{equation}
Det(M_1)=a_1a_2a_3+b_1b_2b_3+c_1c_2c_3-a_1b_2c_3-a_2b_3c_1-a_3b_1c_2>0
\end{equation}

Comment: very good question. I suggest you start with a rank 1 update, where the variation is linear : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219731/determinant-of-rank-one-perturbations-of-invertible-matrices

Comment: Don't you need $a,b,c$ to be positive? Otherwise $a=-2, b=c=-1$ is a counterexample to your first inequality.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out! I forgot this condition.

Comment: @YYF I know an inequality could immediate solve this problem, sadly I don't find any English reference on it. If you have a translator you can read [this](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/b1880b1d2dc58bd63186bceb19e8b8f67d1cefe8.html).

Comment: @Zerox Thank you for the reference. It seems to be called as rearrangement inequality in English https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the reference given by @Zerox, the porblem can be solve using the inequality mentioned above.

However, for the strict inequality, a sufficient condition may be given by $a_i\le b_j\le c_k$, and either $\max a_i< \min b_j$ or $\max b_j<\max c_k$ is satisfied.

A two dimensional case can be shown using $(b_j-a_j)(b_i-a_i)>0$, and rearranging terms,
$$a_ia_j+b_ib_j>a_ib_j-a_jb_i$$
now
\begin{align}
a_1a_2a_3+b_1b_2b_3+c_1c_2c_3&>a_1b_2b_3+a_2a_3b_1+c_1c_2c_3\\
&>a_1b_2c_3+a_2a_3b_1+c_1c_2b_3\\
&>a_1b_2c_3+a_3b_1c_2+a_2b_3c_1
\end{align}
all inequality holds by the two dimensional case, the first exchange first two terms  using $a_1<b_1$ and $a_2a_3<b_2b_3$.

The second inequality exchange first and third terms, using $a_1b_2<c_1c_2$ and $b_3<c_3$.

And the last inequality use $a_3b_1<b_3c_1$ and $a_2<c_2$.

If one of the above inequality is a strict larger one, the strictly greater than $0$ will follows.