# Is the determinant of the Householder reflector $I - 2\hat{x}\hat{x}^\top$ always $-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, projection-matrices

What is the determinant of the following [Householder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) matrix

$$ I - 2\hat{x}\hat{x}^\top $$

where $\hat{x}$ is a normalized vector, i.e., $\|\hat{x}\| = 1$?

I have been told this is always $-1$ somehow but can't find proof of it anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219731/determinant-of-rank-one-perturbations-of-invertible-matrices

Comment: @user326159 thank you, that's very helpful!

Comment: @Physics_Student From the information in the linked question, you should now be able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of the matrix $\hat{x} \hat{x}^T $ are $(n-1)$ zeros and one eigenvalue of $1$.  Therefore, the eigenvalues of $(I - 2 \hat{x} \hat{x}^T) $ are $(n-1)$ $1's$ and one eigenvalue of $(-1)$.  Since the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues, then the determinant will be $(-1)$.