# Determinant of $n \times n$ matrix given diagonal and non diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant, matrix-equations

Let $M$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix with all diagonal entries equal to $r$ and all non-diagonal entries equal to $s$. Compute the determinant of $M$. This was a question from ISI M.Math test $2021$.

My attempt: I tried directly computing for small $n$ to see if there are any patterns. For $n=1,2,3$ the determinants are respectively $r, r^2-s^2, r^3+2s^3-3rs^2$. I couldn't find any pattern other than the obvious fact that there has to an entry $r^n$ for each $n$ so that the identity matrix satisfies the formula. And the sum of the coefficients must be zero for $n>1$ (by having a matrix with all entries equal to $1$). But I can't proceed any further.

Comment: See Andrea's answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206/how-to-calculate-the-determinant-of-all-ones-matrix-minus-the-identity

Comment: $M=(r-s)I_n+see^T$ where $e$ denotes the vector of ones. It follows that you can determine the eigenvalues of $M$ if you can determine the eigenvalues of $A=ee^T$. Since $A$ is a rank-one matrix, it has $n-1$ zero eigenvalues and the remaining eigenvalue is equal to the trace of $A$.

Comment: The decomposition just given by @user1551 is a "Rank-one update of a scalar matrix". A Google search with this type of query will bring you many answers such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/219785/305862).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Determinant

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

> Let $M$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix with all diagonal entries equal to $r$ and all non-diagonal entries equal to $s$. Compute the determinant of $M$.

I would rewrite $M=(r-s)I+A$ where $A$ is a matrix whose entries are identically $s$.

Now, it is easy to check that eigenvalues of $A$ are

- $0$ (by linear dependence of rows) and
- $ns$ (by constant row sum)

with algebraic multiplicities $n-1$ and $1$ respectively.

The eigenvalues of $(r-s)I+A$ will be $(r-s)+0$ and $(r-s)+ns$ with same multiplicities.

Determinant being product of eigenvalues, we have $$\det(M)=(r-s)^{n-1}(r-s+ns)$$

The [question in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206/how-to-calculate-the-determinant-of-all-ones-matrix-minus-the-identity) is a special case.